# How to fetch single row in sequelize while that model is a part of Include in your query

Tags: sequelize.js

So i have a query here which says:

```
ABC.find({ include: XYZ })
```

This returns few instances of XYZ where i need just one latest instance of XYZ. Any clue how to add limit or findOne within the include functionality in sequelize.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add Order by clause like

```
ABC.find({
    where: {
        column1: 'XYZ'
    }, 
    order: [['updatedDate':'DESC']]
});
```

This will return the last updated row only where column1's values is 'XYZ'